# Pass entire model to helper function in underscore template

Tags: underscore.js, marionette, underscore.js-templating

We are using `underscore.js` templates within our application currently; we have a couple helper functions that handle some repetitive operations for us.

Is there a way to pass the entire current scope to the helper function?

Comment: An Underscore template is just a function (that uses `with` for namespace trickery) and your helper would be another function. So call the template function with everything it needs and pass the appropriate variables to your helper. What am I missing?

Comment: The template function is called with everything it needs, call it object x. The helper function, which is used in other places as well, is expecting object x to be passed in, not the value of several properties on object x.

Comment: So you're saying `template_function(x)` and you want access to `x` inside the template? Would be super easy if you said `template_function({ x: x })` instead.

Comment: That wouldn't be awful, but would be tough to do in this situation. The code in question is Marionette, so we aren't explicitly calling the template function in the first place.

Comment: Have a look at the structure of the template function (see the `x.source` in `x = _.template(s)`) and you'll see how they work internally. You can, of course, do `t.call(...)` tricks to set `this` in the template function (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Q4hf8/) but I don't know how to get that past Marionette. If you can `.call` then you can `.bind` to set `this`, sneaking a bound template past Marionette might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Marionette, you might want to leverage [`templateHelpers`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewtemplatehelpers). In your view:

```
var view = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#my-template",

    templateHelpers: {
        model: function() {
            return this;  // `this` will be the model passed in to the view
        }
    }
});

// Or, define as object rather than helper function
var view2 = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#my-template",

    templateHelpers: function () {
        return {
            model: this
        }
    }
});
```

And in your template:

```
<% model().propertyName %>

<!-- Using the alternate format -->
<% model.propertyName %>
```

If you are just using underscore's templating system without Marionette, as mentioned in the comments, you just need to pass an object with your model as the key instead of just the model:

```
model = {'propertyName': 'someValue'};
template = _.template('<% model.propertyName %>');

// Instead of `template(model)`
template({'model': model});
```

Answer (score 1):

a bit late.. and concerning Marionette

, but just needed to do something like this and used arguments[0] inside the template to send the entire model, bound to the template to another function:

```
<script type="text/html" id="someTemplate">
 ...render some stuff
 <%= getMoreHtml(arguments[0]) %>
</script>


then 
getMoreHtml(model) { 
   //return some html where model is the serialized model passed to the prev template
}
```

this works since the model is passed to the Marionette.Renderer.render method and inside of it the data is passed as the only argument to the templateFunc